# Question on using Array

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I could do

```
vars3d = Array[Through[{x, y, z}@#] &, 5]
```

to obtain

```
{{x[1], y[1], z[1]}, {x[2], y[2], z[2]}, {x[3], y[3], z[3]}, {x[4], y[4], z[4]}, {x[5], y[5], z[5]}}
```

I'd tried to obtain the following (expected output)

```
  {{x[6], y[6], z[6]}, {x[9], y[9], z[9]}, {x[10], y[10], z[10]}}
```

by doing

```
vl = {6, 9, 10}
vars3d = Array[Through[{x, y, z}@#] &, vl] # this isn't right.
```

I would like to know how to obtain the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *have to* use `Array`:

```
Array[Through @ {x, y, z} @ vl[[#]] &, Length @ vl]
```

> ```
>  {{x[6], y[6], z[6]}, {x[9], y[9], z[9]}, {x[10], y[10], z[10]}}
> ```

Also:

```
f = Through /@ # /@ #2 &;

f[{x, y, z}, vl]
```

> ```
>  {{x[6], y[6], z[6]}, {x[9], y[9], z[9]}, {x[10], y[10], z[10]}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I can see at least three ways:

```
Through[{x, y, z}[#]] & /@ vl
```

Or alternatively:

```
Transpose[# /@ vl & /@ {x, y, z}]
```

Or alternatively:

```
Outer[#2[#1]&, vl, {x, y, z}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

vl = {6, 9, 10};

vars3d = Array[Through[{x, y, z}@vl[[#]]] &, 3]

(* {{x[6], y[6], z[6]}, {x[9], y[9], z[9]}, {x[10], y[10], z[10]}} *)

{x[#], y[#], z[#]} & /@ vl

(* {{x[6], y[6], z[6]}, {x[9], y[9], z[9]}, {x[10], y[10], z[10]}} *)

Table[{x[n], y[n], z[n]}, {n, vl}]

(* {{x[6], y[6], z[6]}, {x[9], y[9], z[9]}, {x[10], y[10], z[10]}} *)

% == %% == %%%

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vl = {6, 9, 10};
```

Using `Comap` (new in 14.0)

```
Comap[{x, y, z}] /@ vl
```

{{x[6], y[6], z[6]}, {x[9], y[9], z[9]}, {x[10], y[10], z[10]}}

Answer (score 1):

```
vl = {6, 9, 10};
```

---

Another variant using `Array`:

```
Map[Array[Splice@Through[{x, y, z}@#] &, 1, #] &]@vl

(*{{x[6], y[6], z[6]}, {x[9], y[9], z[9]}, {x[10], y[10], z[10]}}*)
```

Or using `Thread`:

```
f = Activate[Thread[Thread[#1 @@ #2] & @@@ Thread[{#1, Inactive[#2]}]]] &;

f[{x, y, z}, vl]

(*{{x[6], y[6], z[6]}, {x[9], y[9], z[9]}, {x[10], y[10], z[10]}}*)
```